# How to export newman report without secrets?

Tags: postman, newman, postman-newman

I have to generate a [newman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman) JSON report for my APIs test results and then upload it somewhere.

The problem with the default [JSON reporter](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman#json-reporter) is that it renders all my environment variables even the ones I set as `secret`.

I created a small mock collection to show that:

[image: postman environment]

Environment snippet:

```
{
    "id": "1bb352fe-fdcf-4a18-942b-a83270fa6fbd",
    "name": "Comments Fake API Env",
    "values": [
        {
            "key": "commentId",
            "value": "1",
            "type": "default",
            "enabled": true
        },
        {
            "key": "secretCommentId",
            "value": "2",
            "type": "secret",
            "enabled": true
        },
        {
            "key": "Some_disabled_var",
            "value": "",
            "type": "default",
            "enabled": false
        }
    ],
    "_postman_variable_scope": "environment",
    "_postman_exported_at": "2023-02-17T21:00:41.635Z",
    "_postman_exported_using": "Postman/10.9.4"
}
```

Collection snippet:

```
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "1d347975-eedd-4f5c-a58d-36cdd7b77794",
        "name": "Dummy comments API",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "Gat all",
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://dummyjson.com/comments?page=30",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "dummyjson",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "comments"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "page",
                            "value": "30"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Get by Id",
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://dummyjson.com/comments/{{commentId}}",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "dummyjson",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "comments",
                        "{{commentId}}"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Get by secret ID",
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://dummyjson.com/comments/{{secretCommentId}}",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "dummyjson",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "comments",
                        "{{secretCommentId}}"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ]
}
```

And if I run newman with JSON reporter

```
newman run  -e ./environment.json ./collection.json
```

I see that the values are rendered

```
cat newman/report.json | jq '.environment.values'

[
  {
    "type": "any",
    "value": "1",
    "key": "commentId"
  },
  {
    "type": "any",
    "value": "2",
    "key": "secretCommentId"
  },
  {
    "type": "any",
    "value": "",
    "key": "Some_disabled_var"
  }
]
```

I did some search online and I didn't find any workarounds or fixes for this. I am working on [my custom reporter](https://github.com/Fcmam5/newman-reporter-json-xt) but it is not going well as all what I receive from newman's event emitter is an object with `environments` already rendered and all variable types are set to `any` so there's no way that I can filter them out without a hacky way of listing them from my `environment.json` file before I run newmann.

I believe that this might be a bug or at least a non-implemented feature so I [filed an issue](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/3070) and I'm still waiting for an answer from the maintainers

So my question is: How to get a `newman` report without any secrets?

Answer (score 1):

You have a workaround option tile Postman support your [filed an issue](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/3070)

Filter only "enabled": true fields from `environment.json` by in-house `node.js` program.

Install dependency for `node.js`

```
npm install fs
```

Save as `convert.js` file name.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const environment = fs.readFileSync('environment.json');
const varaibles = JSON.parse(environment);
console.log(varaibles);

const filtered_collection = {
    "id": varaibles.id,
    "values": varaibles.values.filter((x) => { return x.enabled == true }),
    "name": varaibles.name,
    "_postman_variable_scope": varaibles._postman_variable_scope,
    "_postman_exported_at": varaibles._postman_exported_at,
    "_postman_exported_using": varaibles._postman_exported_using
}
const new_varables = JSON.stringify(filtered_collection, null, 4)
console.log(new_varables);

fs.writeFileSync('environment-no-credential.json', new_varables);
```

Running with converted `environment-no-credential.json` and missed credential variables.

```
newman run  -e ./environment-no-credential.json ./collection.json --env-var "varaible1=your_varaible1" --env-var "varaible2=your_varaible2"
```

#### Demo

I will shows getting Spotify access-token and display `genre` with this methods.
There are two requests.

[image]

Confirmed running collection is passed.

[image]

Export after unchecked for credentials variables

#### *Note - unchecked `client_id` and `client_secret`

Those will export with `values.enabled` is false in `environment.json`

[image]

[image]

#### convert from `environment.json` to `environment-no-credential.json`

blue box is with `all variables`
red box is without `credential variables`

[image]

#### Run with `environment-no-credential.json` and 'collection.json` and credential variables.

```
newman run  -e ./environment-no-credential.json ./collection.json --env-var "client_id=<your_client_id>" --env-var "client_secret=<your_client_secret>"
```

Result
[image]

#### Final conclusion

You can export your environment variables with un-checked enable,

convert from `environment.json` to `environment-no-credential.json`

then run `newman` with credential variables by `--env-var` option.